# Declaring more than one button in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a webpage that has 2 buttons performing different actions. WHen i click on one button, it is performing both the functions but i want it to perform just one function.

**TASK 3.1: 200x200 green box div:**

```
<button>Remove</button>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("div").remove();
        });
    });
    <br/>
</script>

<button>Animate</button>
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("div").animate({ left:'300px' });
        });
    });
</script>

<div style="
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px; 
    padding: 25px; 
    border: 25px solid green;
    margin: 25px; 
    position: absolute;">
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question/error?

Answer (score 2):

The selector `"button"` matches *every* button in the document at that time. When a selector matches multiple elements, the `$.fn.click` method actually loops over that resulting collection and binds to each and every element matched.

If you'd like to match only particular elements, you'll need to distinguish them from other matched elements. One of the most common ways to do this if by giving them a unique ID:

```
<button id="remove">Remove</button>
<button id="animate">Animate</button>
```

And then target those specifically from your scripting:

```
$("#remove").click(function remove () {
    $("div").remove(); // This removes every div from the document
});

$("#animate").click(function animate () {
    $("div").animate({ left: 300 }); // Animates the left property of every div
});
```

Comment: Nicely explained, rather than just stating the obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a different `id` or `class` to each button. You can also condense both scripts into one. Also, seems that instead of using a `div` selector, you should also assign a specific `id` or `class` to the `div`s.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button1").click(function(){
            $("div").remove();
        });

        $("#button2").click(function(){
            $("div").animate({
                left:'300px' 
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Calling them "button1" and "button2" is a horrible idea. Use meaningful names.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="bremove"> Remove</button>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button#bremove").click(function(){
            $("div").remove();
                                    });
                                });
    <br/>
</script>

<button id="banimate"> Animate</button>
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button#banimate").click(function(){
            $("div").animate({
                left:'300px' 
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are bad, because they don't help anyone learn from mistakes. Explain why the original didn't work, what you did to fix it, and why that fixes it.